# How to get a specific frame within a frameset using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My main page:

```
<FRAMESET>
<FRAMESET >
    <FRAME name="menu" src=<%=menu%>>
    <FRAME marginWidth="0" src=<%=bottom%> >
</FRAMESET>
<FRAMESET>
    <FRAME src=<%=title%>>
    <FRAME name="main"src=<%=main%>>
</FRAMESET>
```

I want to get the menu frame using the `name attribute` selector instead of the `frames[index]`, so I want to replace the static selector:

`window.parent.frames[0].document`

for something with jQuery using name attr.

Comment: don't use framesets, they put severe limits on the contents and they cannot be reasonably styled. They're also deprecated in HTML5, by the way.

Comment: What would be the alternative?

Comment: If you absolutely need to use frames (which you never do), use the inline ones. I believe ASP can do some basic templating work (which is the intention behind framesets).